# PDF bookmarks not leveled, while TOC is

Tags: bookmarks

I am using a document style. In terms of outline, i use chapters > sections > subsections.

It compiles, and works fine. The table of contents is correctly indented like

- chapter1
- ___section 1.1
- ______subsection 1.1.1

(However i use Tocdepth 1, this is an example). My file outline shows a similar pattern. However, upon downloading the file, in both Edge browser as well as Adobe pdf, the bookmarks are all on the same level, e.g.

- chapter1
- section 1.1
- subsection 1.1.1

Below is my hyperref setup

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % true: colored text; false: boxed text
    linkcolor=gray,        % color of internal links 
    citecolor=gray,       % color of citations 
    urlcolor=gray,      % color of external links 
    linkbordercolor={1 1 1}, % not used
    citebordercolor={1 1 1}, % not used
    urlbordercolor={1 1 1},   % not used
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=false, 
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksdepth=1,
    linktocpage=false,
    pdfauthor={myname},
    pdftitle={myfile},
}
```

And here is a snippet of the main.tex

```
\begin{document}
% --- title page ----
\input{General/Titlepage.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
% -- abstract etc --
\input{Chapters/Abstract & Preface}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
% --- overview of items ----
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\input{Chapters/Abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\input{Chapters/Abbreviations}
```

After which more chapters follow.

any suggestions on how to adress this problem?

Comment: snippets are evil. Make a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it *much* easier to test your issue.